# iPhone viewwillappear on application entering foreground

Tags: iphone, viewwillappear

I have an application where there are 3 tabs to calculate distance and all. When I first launch the app, on clicking 3 rd tab some network call is happening. Now I put the application to background.
When the application comes to foreground, it should call viewwillappear to go for the network call again. but it is not happening. it is not calling viewwillappear.

How can I check when application comes to foreground, it should check for 3rd tab and call network method

Please help me

Comment: You only want to call that network call when app is coming in foreground right?

Comment: yes, but it should check if the 3rd tab is selected. else it should not call

Comment: yes .. do that Rajneesh has written ... call that network call function in applicationWillEnterForeground

Comment: okay ... then you can set some flag over there and check whether that flag is true ... if yes then call the network function

Comment: Chk  my updated answer, this will check the selected tab....

Answer (score 1):

When application comes to foreground,

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

of the app delegate is called.

You can restart all your paused tasks in:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

Comment: for checking the selected tab item you can use: self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag or UITabBarController has a selectedViewController and a selectedIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%d",tabBar.selectedIndex);
    if (tabBar.selectedIndex == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Your work");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //save in NSUserDefaults (or wherever) which tab is currently active
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // read from NSUserDefaults which tab was active before, 
    // and use an IF statement to control the further behavior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
           if(tab3){
          [viewController3 netWorkCallFromHere];
    } 

}
```

in this approach you will have to declare BOOL tab3 in Appdelegate.

set it true in third viewController and set it false in another viewController .

when it returns from the background then it will check the flag and it will work accordingly.